# Is this algorithm for robust estimation of the covariance matrix sensible?

Tags: covariance-matrix, algorithms, computational-statistics, robust, m-estimation

I have a high dimensional dataset $\bf{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, which is multimodal and has outliers. I want to estimate a robust measure of association, something like the correlation between two sets of random vectors $\{ \bf{x}_1, \ldots \bf{x}_n \}$ and $\{\bf{y}_1, \ldots \bf{y}_n\}$ in $\bf{X}$. I prefer something that I can code myself without too much work. Someone suggested in passing that

1. I want to look at methods for covariance estimation
2. simple and more straightforward implementations would be shrinkage methods (like Ledoit-Wolf) or M-estimators.

I was less interested in the shrinkage estimators because the dataset doesn't seem sparse. Also, having looked at some implementations of the Minimum Covariance Determinant, it seems too complex. Then I looked at M-estimators and wondered if I could use the Huber function to weigh the data when calculating the empirical covariance. The following is the pseudocode I cooked up:

```
# given X formed by stacking the vectors in x and y

scale_factor = 1.345
deviations = X - mean(X)
abs_deviations = abs(deviations)

weights = where(                       # apply conditional element-wise 
     abs_deviations <= scale_factor,   # condition
     1.0,                              # if true
     scale_factor / abs_deviations     # else
)

weighted_deviations = weights * deviations
covariance = weighted_deviations.T @ weighted_deviations  / (num_samples -1)
```

I did some quick and dirty tests with simulated data, and the pseudocode seemed alright? But honestly, I'm not familiar with robust statistics, and I'm guessing here. Is this a correct or reasonable way to estimate the covariance matrix?

Comment: The standard "robust measure of association" is the Spearman correlation coefficient.  Why won't that serve your needs?

Comment: I simply didn't think of the Spearman correlation. On reflection, there's no reason why I can't create a Spearman correlation matrix, but I'm not sure how I could define a meaningful rank order on the data vectors.

Comment: I'm trying to do something related to whitening the relationship between the two sets. I'm not sure that my question is particularly clear or if my problem is well-formulated.

Comment: I don't see what the relationship might be between a robust estimate of covariance and ranking vectors.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've misunderstood your comment. You said above "Why won't [the Spearman correlation coefficient] serve your needs?". My memory of the Spearman correlation coefficient is that it is defined on ranked variables, so to calculate the Spearman coefficient I would need to put a linear order on my variables which are vectors.

Comment: I see.  But that's incorrect: you rank each component separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146566/discussion-between-machineepsilon-and-whuber).